# Не перерисовываются объекты в Windows 7

Tags: windows, c++

Добрый день!
 Такая ситуация: есть UI на WTL. На windows xp все хорошо работает. Тот же проект на Windows 7 - не перерисовываются некоторые объекты.

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: WTL не входит в состав VC++, но скачать с офсайта "микромягких" и "прилинковать" проблем не составит. Проект придется перекомпилить. P.S. Смотрел по сайту - там только для Win Vista :)? Короче, необходимо покопаться в сети.

Comment: проблем с установкой WTL нет. Все работает, но в одном месте ( в одном диалоге ) не перерисовываются контролы, пока на них мышкой не наведешь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В win7 сильно оптимизирован вывод на экран, поэтому в некоторых сценариях обновление экрана само по себе может не происходить. Я в таких случаях спасался принудительным вызовом Invalidate + Update в конкретных случаях. Вызов делал отложенным, через PostMessage. Т.е., например, в конце обработчик InitDialog делаю PostMessage своего сообщения, а в обработчике этого своего сообщения вызываю Invalidate и UpdateWindow.

Comment: идея хорошая. тоже пробовал. не рисуются
вот если сделать sh_hide sw_show - то все ок.
или GetDlgItem(..)->Invalidate() тоже ок.
просто интересно, почему так происходит :)

Comment: Еще, возможно, контролы просто закрашиваются диалогом. Попробуйте поставить диалогу стиль WS_CLIPCHILDREN, иногда помогает.

Comment: и с этим все норм:)
если бы не стоял этот стиль - тогда бы наверно и на ХР бы не рисовалось.
магия какая то :)